# How to input Tensor of variable shape into input Layer and then Dense Layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, valueerror

I made a custom generator function to read in CSV files storing MFCC values for speaker recognition, the files are kept in the same format as image files are kept in Image Data Generator of tensor-flow.

While using `Model.fit()` with a simple Dense Layer Model it is giving Value
Error :

The shape of MFCC values is variable usually 15561, and 15639 how to input the tensors into the layer ??

```
    import re
    import tensorflow as tf
    tf.__version__2.2.0
    
    def tf_data_generator(file_list, batch_size = 1):
        i = 0
        while True:
            if i*batch_size >= len(file_list):  
            i = 0
            np.random.shuffle(file_list)
        else:
            file_chunk = file_list[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size] 
            data = []
            labels = []
            label_classes = tf.constant(["1034", "1039", "1044", "1048", "1050", "1055", "1061"...]) 
            for file in file_chunk:
                temp = pd.read_csv(open(file,'r'), header=None)
                data.append(temp.values.reshape(-1, 1)) 
                pattern = tf.constant(eval('file[6:10]'))  
                for j in range(len(label_classes)):
                    if re.match(pattern.numpy(), label_classes[j].numpy()): 
                        labels.append(j)
            data = np.asarray(data)
            data = tf.reshape(data, [-1])
            labels = np.asarray(labels)
            yield data, labels
            i = i + 1

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(tf_data_generator,  args = [list_path, 1], output_types= (tf.float32,tf.float32))

    num = 0

    for data, labels in dataset:
        print(data.shape, labels.shape,"\n")
        print(labels, "<--Labels")  # Just to see the lables
        print()
        num = num + 1
    if num > 5: break
```

## Output:

```
(15561,) (1,) 

tf.Tensor([0.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32) <--Labels

(15561,) (1,) 

tf.Tensor([0.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32) <--Labels

(15561,) (1,) 

tf.Tensor([0.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32) <--Labels

(15639,) (1,) 

tf.Tensor([1.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32) <--Labels

(15639,) (1,) 

tf.Tensor([1.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32) <--Labels

(15561,) (1,) 

tf.Tensor([1.], shape=(1,), dtype=float32) <--Labels

from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Input, Masking
Model = Sequential([Input(shape=(15561,), dtype = np.float32),
               Dense( units = 10, activation='relu'),
               Dense(units=10, activation = 'softmax')
            ])
Model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['acc'], optimizer = 'Adam')
history = Model.fit(dataset, epochs = 1, steps_per_epoch=512)
```

## ValueError:

Input 0 of layer sequential_5 is incompatible with the layer: its rank is undefined, but the layer requires a defined rank.

Comment: It seems that your inputs are either (15561, 1) or (15639). So you could pad all inputs with shape (15561, 1) with zeros and transform them also to have the shape (15639, 1). What also comes to my mind is "global average pooling" but I am not sure if that is a possible solution but you can seach for it on the internet.

Comment: i solved the issue by padding the layers but it gives another error

Comment: InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[16900,315] labels_size=[315,315]